# How to use flexbox to create columns in <li> elements

Tags: flexbox

How can I make this have the buttons in the same column as each other?

```
ul
  li
    p button
    p button
```

using flexbox
if the p has different width the buttons are shifted.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox has no grid notion.

Instead, you can use CSS tables

```css
ul {
  display: table;
}
li {
  display: table-row;
}
p, button {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Short</p>
    <button>Foo</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Long long long text</p>
    <button>Bar</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```